# (AVB)&(AV~B) is logically equivalent to ~~A, it that true or false?

Tags: math, logic

(AVB)&(AV~B) is logically equivalent to ~~A?
It kind of confused me since they are in different dimension.

Comment: It is "A" (which is also ~~A)

Comment: @ThomasJager Yeah but I got it wrong. I only used the truth table to compare the results instead of your math method...

Comment: I'm not sure where my original comment went, but I've updated my answer to show this being done with truth tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from:

```
(A∨B)∧(A∨¬B)
```

One can first apply one of De Morgan's laws to the **AND**:

```
¬(¬(A∨B)∨¬(A∨¬B))
```

Next, one of De Morgan's laws can be applied to each side:

```
¬((¬A∧¬B)∨(¬A∧B))
```

By applying distributivity of **AND** over **OR** in reverse, `¬A` can be extracted:

```
¬(¬A∧(¬B∨B))
```

By complementation, `¬B∨B` is `1`:

```
¬(¬A∧1)
```

By identity for **AND**:

```
¬¬A
```

Applying double negation:

```
A
```

---

This goes through your target `¬¬A` without going through simple `A`. It's much simpler not to do that.

Starting again from:

```
(A∨B)∧(A∨¬B)
```

By applying distributivity of **OR** over **AND** in reverse, `A` can be extracted:

```
A∨(B∧¬B)
```

By complementation, `B∨¬B` is `1`:

```
A∧1
```

By identity for **AND**:

```
A
```

Applying double negation in reverse:

```
¬¬A
```

---

Since you mention doing it by truth table, here's my go at showing that they're equivalent that way:

```
+---+---+----+----+-------+--------+--------------+-----+
| A | B | ¬A | ¬B | (A∨B) | (A∨¬B) | (A∨B)∧(A∨¬B) | ¬¬A |
+---+---+----+----+-------+--------+--------------+-----+
| 0 | 0 |  1 |  1 |   0   |    1   |       0      |  0  |
| 0 | 1 |  1 |  0 |   1   |    0   |       0      |  0  |
| 1 | 0 |  0 |  1 |   1   |    1   |       1      |  1  |
| 1 | 1 |  0 |  0 |   1   |    1   |       1      |  1  |
+---+---+----+----+-------+--------+--------------+-----+
```